# добавление в корзину

Tags: javascript, jquery

подскажите как реализовать добавление в корзину на jquery, получилось сделать добавление количества товара, а вот цену распарсить не получается,вот код

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.header__menu a i').click(function() {
        $('.sub-menu').toggle()
      })

      //тут кол-во товара
      $('.add-tovar').click(function() {
        $("#tovar").text(parseInt($("#tovar").text()) + 1);
      })

      //тут должна прибавляться цена товара
      $('.add-tovar').click(function() {
        $(".cost").text(parseInt($(".cost").text()),
          $("#cena").text(parseInt($("#cena").text()) + $(".cost")
          })
      })


      //сама корзина, .cost это в карточке товара сама цена
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bassket">
  <p>
    Товаров:<span id="tovar">0</span> Цена:
    <span id="cena">0</span>
  </p>
  <i class="fas fa-shopping-basket"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.header__menu a i').click(function() {
    $('.sub-menu').toggle()
  })

  //тут кол-во товара
  $('.add-tovar').click(function() {
    $("#tovar").text(parseInt($("#tovar").text()) + 1);
  })

  //тут должна прибавляться цена товара
  $('.add-tovar').click(function() {
      // Get total 
      var total = $('#cena').attr('data-total-price')
      // Set total converting it to number 
      total = +$(".cost", this).attr('data-price') + (+total)
      $('#cena').attr('data-total-price', total)
      //----------------------------------------------------------------
      // Set price veiw
      $("#cena").text('$' + total)
  })
})


//сама корзина, .cost это в карточке товара сама цена
```

```css
.add-tovar{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="bassket">
<!-------- shelf -------->
 <div class="shelf">
  <div class="car add-tovar">
    <i class="fas fa-car"></i>
    <span class="cost" data-price="20000">Price: $20,000</span> 
  </div> 
  <hr>
  <div class="camera add-tovar">
  <i class="fas fa-camera"></i>
  <span class="cost" data-price="1000">Price: $1,000</span> 
  </div> 
 </div> 
 <!-------- end shelf -------->
 <hr>
  <p>
    Товаров:<span id="tovar">0</span> Цена:
    <span id="cena" data-total-price="0">0</span>
  </p>
  <i class="fas fa-shopping-basket"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое дружище